# Disable animation in Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My question is how we can disable button or checkbox animation in angular material widgets?

There are some css solutions to override transition with none but it s not working.

Thanks,

Comment: import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-
        browser/animations'; for the whole module

Comment: what id I just want to disable for checkbox not other components?

Comment: Actually, I just switched to NoopAnima.. and nothing changed!

Comment: NoopAnimationsModule removes some animations, but keeps others. For example, dialogs start to appear in their desired position without a slide/fade effect, but there is still fade effect for backdrop, labels moving in and out of inputs and similar. Bottom line - it's still slow in IE11 with NoopAnimationsModule.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can disable animation using @.disabled property which is introduced in angular [4.3.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#431-2017-07-19).

Either add below code to your component

```
@HostBinding('@.disabled') disabled = true
```

or in your html

```
<div [@.disabled]="expression"></div>
```

Here is working plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/sVJM8H?p=preview

Comment: Which animation you want to disable in mat-select?

Comment: If you are talking about the popup, that is not possible with it..I have also tried earlier.

Comment: Worked for me!  <mat-tab-group [@.disabled]="true">
        <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>

Comment: tnx! I was looking for it in angular2 and didn't find it. 
It's only from  angular 4.3.1. TNX MAN!

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
<mat-group [@.disabled]="true">
    <mat-tab label="one">one</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="two">two</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="three">three</mat-tab>
</mat-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is a hackie with route navigation (find a place later to change returned value)

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
    return false;
};
this.router.navigate(['your-page', nextTabIndex]);
```

This will be same as `*ngIf` condition but also it's important to define a route param, e.g. `:tab`

```
{
   path: 'your-path/:tab',
   component: YourComponent
}
```

And of corse you should use `<route-outlet></route-outlet>`

And also it'll be nice to restore current tab on page reload

```
tab: number = 0;

constructor(public router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.tab = this.route.snapshot.params['tab'];
}

onTab(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.tab = event.index;
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
        return false;
    };
    const url = decodeURIComponent(this.router.url);
    this.router.navigate([url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")), event.index]);
}
```

And in  html

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tab" (selectedTabChange)="onTab($event)"/>
```