# Get angular is not defined when using allowAnimations

Tags: protractor

I'm getting error of angular is not defined when using allowAnimation(false)

```
fit('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();

    element(by.css('body')).allowAnimations(false);

    expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('Welcome to compressor!');
  });
```

I want to disable animations on body when test using protractor

log:

```sh
Failed: javascript error: angular is not defined
        (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)
        (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628411 (3324f4c8be9ff2f70a05a30ebc72ffb013e1a71e),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)
          ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue and from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e77885d7a60fd5a56bf624a5307fd41582f10bca/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L781) for the function that is executed it appears to be using the `angular` keyword in the browser which is associated with AngularJS(1) not the latest versions. In other words this functions was designed to work with AngularJS and not Angular2+.

There are some workarounds, [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745877/disable-animation-in-angular-2-material?rq=1), but they do require making changes to the angular code itself.

You could probably raise this as a bug for this but from looking at that file there are a number of functions affected (such as locating by.model) so they likely are aware of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that maybe this is an issue, but as you can see protractor has almost 4 hundred issues opened, seems it couldn't be fixed soon, so I will find another workaround solutions