# ng5-slider high value sets in wrong position

Tags: angular, slider

I'm using ng5-sliders in mat-menu but the high value of each slider sets in wrong position, not on the edge of slider.

I tried some solutions eg. [manual refresh](https://angular-slider.github.io/ng5-slider/demos#manual-refresh-slider)
but it doesn't work

There is example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8c46ta)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. Just increase your timeout to 200 & it resolved.

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Options } from 'ng5-slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  displayMenu = true;
filterElement = [
      {
        value: 0,
        highValue: 15,
        options: {
          floor: 0,
          ceil: 15,
          step: 0.1
        },
      },
      {
        value: 1,
        highValue: 1200,
        options: {
          floor: 1,
          ceil: 1200,
        },
      }];
  manualRefresh: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  noClickable($event: MouseEvent) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }
  onMenuOpen() {
      this.displayMenu = true;
  }
  menuToggle(value: boolean) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Test');
        this.manualRefresh.emit();
    }, 200);

  }
}
```

Here is the resource link where I have just change the timeout from 100 to 200

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8c46ta

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was using the ng5-slider in a `MatDialog`. I resolved it by doing a manual refresh in the `afterOpened` subscription of `MatDialogRef`.

I suggest you subscribe to the `menuOpened` event emitter of your menu trigger and do a manual refresh over there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to Angular animations and it can be solved by replacing `BrowserAnimationsModule` with `NoopAnimationsModule` inside the `app.module.ts` file. The disadvantage is that there won't be any animations in the whole application.

See the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bujptb?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Ideally it should be possible to disable animations for a specific `mat-menu`, same as it can be done for other components (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369567/2358409). 
Unfortunately this doesn't work yet for `mat-menu` but there exists an open [feature request](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13017).